# Webpage access with other methods?

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I have this new class "WebPage". I am calling it from a button event in Form1.
The problem is that I Re-Call this entire process of website identification every time I go to a new page on that website. I think this BIG method is needed only one time, when I first access the website. My intuition say that I should use something else than this big code for each other pages on the same website. I am wrong and I should stick with what I have and working already? Or I am right and there are other methods (After) this one ?
Thank you !

(C# code)

```
public class WebPage
{

    public string GetText(string url)
    {
        //Special webpage Reading (extract info from page)
        HttpWebRequest request;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        Stream stream = null;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UserAgent = "Foo";
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        string  text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        if (stream != null) stream.Close();
        if (response != null) response.Close();
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the url changes, then you need to get a new result for that page.

Comment: So, your suggestion is that I should stick with this code I have here?

Comment: I'm not understanding what's wrong with this. You're welcome to cache the results for the same url, but that should be done externally to this method, however you'll also want to implement a "TTL" on that because web pages change over time

Comment: thank you mister  cricket_007 for your answers.
The big problem i have with this method (and i suspect is not a complete one), is that when i navigate on a page, i can read it fine, no problems.But very shortly, and is completely random, it loads some very strange page (my suspicion is a server thing), is always the same, with some javascript algorithm inside it, that checks for n%10, n%8, n%6, n%4, etc and is checking a lot - like a full page of only this checking. And it stay 'blocked' on this page for a couple of minutes - i dont know how many, but is annoying as hell.

Comment: After some minutes, I can reach back the original url but with the random chance it will jump back to that second page again. I kind of resolve it, relatively successful, using a thread.sleep for 1010 ms. But it still got 'blocked' 1 time in a long process i had to make.

Comment: Well, HttpWebRequest won't run Javascript. But that sounds like a server thing that would prevent external bots from scanning a site

Comment: And i find is from inside this method, using breakpoints. Is from a request or response thing. But more than this i dont know at this moment how to fix it.

Comment: I am only reading the pages. One after another, 220 pages in total.

Comment: I imagine that I should use only this BIG method once, and after, use some simple lines with request blabla? response blabla, done. Bypass that timer from their server.

Comment: Also - can you explain to me what is the diference between a browser opening the same page and using this method in c# ? How 'they' figure out its from this code and not from the browser ?

Comment: Depends on the server, but typically it's some combination of headers, such as User-Agent, which you can set from the code to an actual one rather than `Foo`. And as mentioned, you're not running Javascript. For any large web pages, you'll need to read the entire stream, which can indeed take some time... But this method isn't actually that big, and it's all necessary to download the content from a URL

Comment: Oh.. you are mentioning that i am not running javascript in my code. But if I am running it, it is possible to stop that counter from my side using javascript ? Just very curious.

Comment: No. I'm saying that you're opening a network connection to a website and just reading text which happens to be HTML (maybe possibly with script tags). If the web page did have Javascript, C# won't interpret that text and run it. If anything is slow, could be either two things happening... 1) Your URL is behind a site like Cloudflare that will redirect your request while it handles DDoS protection and makes it more difficult to download a page 2) There's just too much content at that url, so it takes time for `sr.ReadToEnd();` to finish

Comment: I am aware that c# does not speak javascript. For case 2 -  is not that much content per page. Is loading it very quickly, when it does it.
Can you explain me more about point 1 please?  I think is very interesting. How can I avoid that redirection from Cloudflare? Or stop DDoS protection maybe? All i need is a workaround if possible. :) Just shooting in the wind here. But if i dont ask, i will not know. I appreciate your answers very much.